# Obtain a customer's first purchase for one year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get as many new customers as I have per month. I know I could get the minimum purchase, but the problem I have is that if a customer had already had a purchase, but stopped buying for more than a year, he is considered a new user again.

You could help me by getting how many new customers I have per month. That is, whose minimum purchase date has been in that month and has not bought anything in the year before that minimum date.

I tried with this code, but if in this case, a customer had his first purchase in February 2019 and then the next purchase was in March 2020, just consider the purchase of February, when he should be new user in February 2019 and March 2020

```
 select to_char(B.fp, 'YYYY-MM') month,  count(B.email)
from(
    select A.email, A.first_purchase fp
    from(
            select email, date(min(created)) first_purchase
            from "Order_table" oo 
            group by email)A
    where A.first_purchase >= (A.first_purchase + INTERVAL '-1 year'))B 
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select to_char(ot.fp, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm
       count(*) filter (where ot.fp > ot.prev_fp + interval '1 year' or b.prev_fp is null) as cnt_new
from (select ot.*, lag(ot.fp) over (partition by ot.email order by ot.fp) as prev_fp
      from Order_table ot
     ) ot
group by yyyymm;
```

Comment: Can you help me by indicating which is the t-table and which is the b-table? It is not very clear to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: THIS IS CORRECT??? : select to_char(c.fp, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm,
       count(*) filter (where c.fp > c.prev_fp + interval '1 year' or c.prev_fp is null) as cnt_new
from (select b.email, b.fp fp , lag(b.fp) over (partition by b.email order by b.fp) as prev_fp
      from (select email, date(min(created)) fp
   from "Order_table" oo 
   where oo.paid = true     
   group by email)b)c
group by yyyymm; @GordonLinoff

Comment: There is only one table.  The aliases should be all the same.